# Qt4 interface not working for VLC

Tags: vlc, qt

This is what happens if I try to run VLC:

```
main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
main interface error: option qt-volume-complete does not exist
skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
```

I tried the command vlc -vv for more details, and apparently the Qt4 UI fails to load because there is an undefined symbol: _mali_clz_lu

It used to work until a few days ago. I've tried removing and installing both vlc and qt4 in all sorts of different ways (also deleting old config files and any kind of cache), what else can I do?

Comment: Can you run 'sudo apt-get install -f' please? It seems that some libraries may have failed to install.

Comment: show us:$vlc -v

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste tried that already, didn't work

Comment: @j0h find the output [here](http://pastebin.com/XaWGemHC)

Comment: try vlc 2.2.0 its in the repos, or here http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html also, find or locate libqt4_plugin.so then, make a link to it in the path where it is currently searching for it because your error is saying file not found.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for trying to help me after 10 months, but I don't even have the device where I encountered the problem anymore, so I can't try any of your solutions or provide the output to the commands you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Install dependencies**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git cmake g++ libqt4-dev qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev \
    qttools5-dev-tools qtquick1-5-dev qtscript5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev \
    libqt5svg5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libssl-dev
   ```
2. **UPDATE:** 
   Qt5.4 is now required. This is not in the default repositories.Check if you already have Qt 5.4 by typing

   ```
   qmake -version
   ```

   in a terminal window. If you don't have 5.4 or later then follow these steps to install it:
3. Download the latest version of Qt from http://qt-project.org/. The file you download is actually an installation script called something like

   ```
   qt-opensource-linux-x64-1.6.0-8-online.run
   ```
4. Move the installer to your Home directory and open a terminal window.
5. Give the installer execute permissions:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-1.6.0-8-online.run
   ```
6. Run the installer:

   ```
   sudo ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-1.6.0-8-online.run
   ```
7. Follow the installation wizard and write down the installation directory (default: `/opt/Qt`. You can choose somewhere else if you want but make sure it doesn't have spaces anywhere in the path). Finish the install.
8. In your file browser, navigate to the installation directory and find the path to the Qt `bin` directory.
9. Add the `bin` directory to your `$PATH` environment variable so that MuseScore knows where it is. Modify the following command with the correct path as appropriate.:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH="/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```
10. Load your new $PATH variable.

    ```
    source ~/.bashrc
    ```
11. Complete! You can check the Qt installation was successful by typing

    ```
    qmake -version
    ```

.