# VLC won't start on Ubuntu 17.10 error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider

Tags: vlc, qt, qt4

VLC won't open GUI. Ubuntu 17.10 on X, all packages are up to date `vlc:amd64/artful 2.2.6-6 uptodate`. Tried system reboot and purging and re-installing VLC. VLC was installed with `sudo apt install vlc`.  Here is the output in console:

```
matias@matias-System-Product-Name:~$ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
[000055fc8c43a918] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface.
Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055fc8c550a28] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider
found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[000055fc8c550a28] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[000055fc8c550a28] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
>
```

Because it suggests a problem with Qt, I tried following the instructions here: [Qt4 interface not working for VLC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458050/qt4-interface-not-working-for-vlc#596061) 
and installed Qt 5.10.1 but it didn't help (verification by qmake -version `Using Qt version 5.10.1 in /opt/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib`)

Using VLC via command line seems to work fine. Here is the output of `vlc -vv` https://pastebin.com/kC86TBN7

I tried to also tag skins2 but not enough rep.