# VLC 3 Won't Start

Tags: software-installation, vlc, qt

- Version: VLC media player 3.0.1 Vetinari (revision 3.0.1-0-gec0f700fcc)
- Ubuntu 18.04

Error:

```
cannot load module `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt_plugin.so' (libQt5Svg.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

How I got there:

- Installed vlc: `sudo apt install vlc`
- Installed qt5 (downloaded from the site, followed through the steps, and added to path. Followed the answer at [Qt4 interface not working for VLC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458050/qt4-interface-not-working-for-vlc).

Here's my entire trace when I do `vlc -vvv`: https://pastebin.com/3wDmGhWV

Comment: Don't add 'more information' as answers.  Use edits for that.  Only post an answer when you *actually* have an answer (you don't state a true way to resolve the problem in your 'answer')

Comment: Please don't use things like `remove vlc*`. It uses regexes instead of globs, and you'll be removing any package that starts with `vl`, not every package that starts with `vlc`.

Comment: @Thomas The 'true way to resolve' was me installing VLC 1) through the software center and 2) the right VLC as there are two options in the software center. In my case that was the solution, and unless there's a reason why on 18.04 VLC via `apt get install vlc` doesn't work. In any case, my answer below *solved* the issue for me. No idea why, but it was the solution. Wasn't the solution I was expecting myself, but worked, at least for me.

Comment: @Thomas since you've deleted the answer that worked, you might as well delete the question, because I had an issue, had a solution and shared the solution but you don't see the solution as a 'true' solution, then you just delete the question as it isn't a 'true' issue. Geeeesh...

Comment: I misread your post at the time - but note this only works if something is using the "Ubuntu Software" method of managing the software; I'll undelete it, but it might not help others using one of the variants of Ubuntu that don't use Ubuntu Software center/installer for their packages.

Comment: @ThomasWard The problem in my post was particular to 18.04. Anyone using anything less likely doesn't or wouldn't have that issue. I didn't when on 16.04 LTS. Only become an issue with 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 18.04 seems to have a problem (at least on my instance) with shared object files that **apt/dpkg** *believes* are installed, but the files are missing.

I solved my problem by running *vlc -vvv* and looking for lines like the following:

```
main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt_plugin.so' (libQt5Svg.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

In this case, it's missing the package *libqt5svg*, which you must *reinstall*:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5svg
```

Keep doing this until all the missing shared object files are restored, and **vlc** will launch.

Unfortunately, this is not just a **vlc** issue, many of my apps are having the same problem.

Comment: In my case, after several tries at re-installation of countless broken packages, I simply re-installed Ubuntu 18.04, but this time round, ticking the "install third party packages" whiles connected to internet.

Comment: Weird, I did that too. But I had other issues with the installation, which may have affected it.

Answer (score 2):

I removed every trace of VLC

```
sudo apt remove '^vlc'
```

Then opened Ubuntu Software, searched "Vlc", then selected the first option.

Not sure what's going on there, but there are 2 VLC in the application store.

Doing `sudo apt install vlc` seems to install the second VLC in the list (with stars) which doesn't work.

But the first one works, yet has no ratings.

[image]