# Can't launch applications installed from Software Center like VLC and Handbrake in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-center, vlc, 18.04

The applications that I install from Software Center like VLC and Handbrake do not open when I click their icons. Pre-installed applications like firefox, LibreOffice, Disks, Thunderbird etc work fine. only the applications I install don't open.

When I type vlc in terminal I get these messages:

[image: skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate dialogs provider]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: vlc is working after following the instruction in this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029380/vlc-3-wont-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the instructions at this link: [VLC 3 Won't Start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029380/vlc-3-wont-start) , not only the vlc is working properly but also all the other apps like Handbrake, Skype , Clementine are working fine!!!